# How do I check if a String contains a numeric value

Tags: java, char

Hello basically I tried to use this code

```
    for(int character=0; character<roomNo.length(); character++){
        if((Character.isDigit(roomNo.charAt(character)))) {
        }
    }
    return true;
```

To loop through a String and see if it contains any numbers. I'm trying to create a method that checks whether a String is numeric, if it is the method should return true. So far it doesn't work? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean by a "numeric value"? Do you consider `-2.3` to be a numeric value? Do you mean a strictly positive integer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    for(int character=0; character<roomNo.length(); character++){
    if(!Character.isDigit(roomNo.charAt(character))) {
         return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Or as others have said, use regular expressions

Comment: The loop here will return `true` *as soon* it sees a digit.

Comment: I modified it. When i read "To loop through a String and see if it contains any numbers" i thought he wants to know if the string contains any number, not ONLY numeric values

Comment: This one worked most easily, does this just mean if it finds a letter it will return false. Basically I'm trying to check a 3 character String on whether its numeric and whether parts of it are within a certain range.

Comment: I'm looking to check the String and if it contains even one letter the method has to return false.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. If you want to check parts of the String, you can use the Integer.parseInt() method on some substrings of that string to get the values. It is something like this: Integer.parseInt(myString.substring(0,1)) . This is if you want to check certain parts of that numeric string to be in a certain range. If you want to take the digits separately, just use the charAt() method and remember that digit 0 has the ASCII code 48. If you want to check if it contains a single letter, use the isLetter() method.

Comment: Only thing i will say is the method i used doesn't really work as it will return true as long as there is 1 number BUT you shouldn't be able to enter letters?

Answer (score 9):

You can check this using regexp:

```
roomNo.matches("\\d+");
```

Comment: @A.R.S. some mysterious processes occur here:)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just do `roomNo.matches("\\d+")`?

`\d` matches any digit and, consequently, `\d+` matches any string of only digits.

Comment: Poor bellum was the first to point that out and has less upvotes :p

Comment: @Keyser i missed at first one important character:)

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a room number, I'm assuming that you're looking for an Integer, so I'd recommend Integer.parseInt().

Comment: Who says there aren't more than 2,147,483,647 rooms? :-)

Comment: Using `parseInt` just to validate a string is unwieldy and a validation failure incurs the additional cost of the exception mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The usual form of an explicit loop for this sort of validation is:

```
for each character in the string
  if not acceptable
    return false
return true
```

There are at least two alternatives that avoid an explicit loop, a regular expression (already suggested) and attempting conversion to the appropriate type in a try-catch.

For example, if you want an integer, call Integer.parseInt and catch NumberFormatException. If the exception happens, return false. If not, return true. The conversion strategy is especially useful for the more complicated formats, such as double.

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like

```
String numbers = "0123456789"
if(numbers.indexOf(roomNo.charAt(character)) >= 0)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using NumberUtils from Apache Commons

[Apache Commons isNumber(String)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber%28java.lang.String%29)

[Apache Commons isDigits(String)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#isDigits%28java.lang.String%29)

Personal preference is to use a proven implementation rather than rolling my own.